# Application crash on CFRelease

Tags: objective-c, core-foundation

Sometimes my application is crashing on `CFRelease(theURL);`

```
CFURLRef theURL = CFURLCreateFromFSRef( kCFAllocatorDefault, inRef );
NSString *currentPath = [(NSURL *)theURL path];
CFRelease(theURL);  

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x92a53354 CFRelease + 36
```

Why?

> The Create Rule
>
> Core Foundation functions have names that indicate when you own a
>   returned object:
>
> Object-creation functions that have “Create” embedded in the name;
>   Object-duplication functions that have “Copy” embedded in the name. If
>   you own an object, it is your responsibility to relinquish ownership
>   (using CFRelease) when you have finished with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `CFRelease` argument is `NULL`, the function will crash. Check the value returned from `CFURLCreateFromFSRef`.